# % as second argument of subst command

Tags: makefile

In a makefile I'm working with I came across a few declarations (simplified below):

```
NAME=name
SRC := name_a.cpp name_b.cpp name_c.cpp name_a.h name_b.h name_c.h

$(subst $(NAME),%,$(SRC)): %.xsd
          ...       
    <other commands>
          ...
```

So what does the % do as the second argument?

Comment: Nothing. It is a literal string. That line is replacing all instances of `name` in the files in `SRC` with `%` for use in a pattern rule target list.

Comment: For the record testing this yourself would have been easy to do. Sticking `$(info Result: $(subst $(NAME),%,$(SRC)))` anywhere after the two variable definition lines and then running `make -q` would have shown you the output.